# ElasticSearch Nested aggregation with filters and query

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, nested, aggregation

I want to calculate median on nested field. Nested field contains of list of objects that have some attributes. I want to filter out some of them before I calculate median.
For example, let's say I have 10 objects in nested field, but only 7 of 10 will be taken for calculating median.

```
query_median = {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "date": "2020-05-18"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "group_name": "some_name"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "median_value": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "people"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "median": {
                    "percentiles": {
                        "field": "people.for_median_attr",
                        "percents": [50]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above query works, but it has no filters. When I want to add additional filters in `aggs`, it gives me the same `value` as in case without any filter. Below what I tried:

```
query_median = {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "date": "2020-05-18"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "group_name": "some_name"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "median_value": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "people"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "filter_out": {
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "people.attr_not_wanted1": False
                                    },
                                    "term": {
                                        "people.attr_not_wanted2": False
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "median": {
                            "percentiles": {
                                "field": "people.for_median_attr",
                                "percents": [50]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example document:

```
{
        "_index" : "some_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "some_id",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "date" : "2020-05-10",
          "group_name" : "some_name",
          "org_code" : "some_code",
          "people" : [
            {
              "nickname" : "xxx",
              "review_count" : 20.0,
              "not_wanted_1" : false,
              "not_wanted_2" : false
            },
            {
              "nickname" : "yyy",
              "review_count" : 18.0,
              "not_wanted_1" : false,
              "not_wanted_2" : false
            },
            {
              "nickname" : "zzz",
              "value_for_median" : 11.0,
              "not_wanted_1" : true,
              "not_wanted_2" : true
            },
            ...
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

In this case, median is calculated only from two numbers: `20` and `18`.

Comment: Can you show a sample document with a nested array containing some element to keep and some to leave out?

Comment: **Val** I added it in initial thread - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. You're just missing a few curly braces in the nested filter and you should pick `true` instead of `false` since you want to keep the nested documents to calculate the median on them.

Your query should look like this:

```
{
  "query": {
     ...
  },
  "aggs": {
    "median_value": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "people"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filter_out": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "people.not_wanted_1": true
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "people.not_wanted_2": true
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "median": {
              "percentiles": {
                "field": "people.value_for_median",
                "percents": [
                  50
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "median_value" : {
      "doc_count" : 3,
      "filter_out" : {
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "median" : {
          "values" : {
            "50.0" : 11.0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Acutally I want to exclude those with both values `true`. So in my case I take all objects that have `not_wanted_1/not_wanted_2 = False`. This query seems to show `'values': {'50.0': None}`

Comment: Ok then you can just change `true` to `false`. however, note that in those elements you don't have any `value_for_median` field.

Comment: Actually I re-arranged your answer to my needs and it's working! Great, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html , you could try updating your 'filter_out' part of the query to this :

```
    "filter_out" : {
      "filters" : {
        "filters" : [
          { "term" : { "people.attr_not_wanted1" : false   }},
          { "term" : { "people.attr_not_wanted2" : false }}
        ]
      }
    }
```